# Best way to refactor a primitive type in a large codebase?

Tags: c#, refactoring, automated-refactoring

In a fairly large codebase we have a 'ElementQuantity' type that was originally chosen to be a `int`.  Now, several years and 100K+ lines of code later, we are overflowing this variable and need it to be a `long`.  This type is used pervasively in the project; a quick grep tells me it is used in literally hundreds of method signatures.

1. Are there refactoring tools that will help make this change over a large codebase?
2. Does C# support some feature like a C++ typedef that allows aliasing primitive types?

Comment: AFAIK: No and no

Comment: The alias for `int` is `Int32` and for `long` is `Int64`... If you did use these, then Resharper (Object Browser => Find Usages) could help, however if you used the primitives, I think your only real option is find & replace

Comment: Yeah, ReSharper is your best friend with this kind of things

Comment: I double checked... Resharper will find all the usages (even of the primitives), but I can't find a way to move them to a differenty type (like you can with complex types)...

Comment: If you have to do this it might be beneficial to create your own class that encapsulates the primitive type. That way if you ever have to change it again you won't have to repeat replacing it everywhere.